# Simple Question: How to split date (08-17-2011) into month, day, year? PHP

Tags: php, variables, date, time, split

I have a variable called $orderdate and it is set to a date format like this mm-dd-yyyy.

In PHP how would I split this variable into $month, $day, $year?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

If you're sure about the format of *input value*, then:

```
$orderdate = explode('-', $orderdate);
$month = $orderdate[0];
$day   = $orderdate[1];
$year  = $orderdate[2];
```

You could also use [`preg_match()`](http://www.php.net/preg_match):

```
if (preg_match('#^(\d{2})-(\d{2})-(\d{4})$#', $orderdate, $matches)) {
    $month = $matches[1];
    $day   = $matches[2];
    $year  = $matches[3];
} else {
    echo 'invalid format';
}
```

Additionally, you can use [`checkdate()`](http://www.php.net/checkdate) to validate the date.

Answer (score 21):

If you are *not certain* about the input format you can also do the following:

```
$time  = strtotime($input);
$day   = date('d',$time);
$month = date('m',$time);
$year  = date('Y',$time);
```

Comment: Its great for easy to use

Comment: This is not true. If i have an input format dd/mm/YYYY then this does not work.
eg if $input = '01/02/2015' then your method gives the day and month the wrong way around!

Comment: That's because strtotime will give you the "wrong" ouput. You should read the top comment over at http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php - Basically, when you use `/` it will assume American locale and assume mm/dd/YYYY

Answer (score 6):

```
list($month, $day, $year) =explode("-",$orderdate);
```

Answer (score 5):

A good approach is to use [date_parse_from_format()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-parse-from-format.php).

For your example:

```php
$dateStr = '03-27-2015';
$dateArray = date_parse_from_format('m-d-Y', $dateStr);
```

This gives `$dateArray` as:

```
Array
(
    [year] => 2015
    [month] => 3
    [day] => 27
    [hour] => 
    [minute] => 
    [second] => 
...
)
```

Comment: This is by far the best answer!. You can even verify that the supplied string is valid date or not! `if (!$dateArray['warning_count'])`

Answer (score 2):

Use `explode` to split string

```
list($m,$d,$y)=explode('-',$date);
```